# Jena program freezing when creating OntModel

Tags: java, c#, jena, owl, ontology

**Background:**

I am currently working with ontologies for storing, manipulating and inferring information. The ultimate goal is to have an Unity program that serves as an interface for manipulating and visualizing such information.
My job here is to provide the ontology structure (I use Protege for this purpose), data feeding programs for the ontology (diferent parsers and non-related to the issue at hands programs) and a set of information retrieving tools to get such information (a C# script that contains methods which fulfill these tasks).

Since the Jena package is actually Java and Unity works within the .NET framework I am importing the libraries from the IKVM to solve this problem.

The ulterior motive of this program is to become a .dll library to be used by the Unity program in charge of the GUI module.

**Problem:**

I have created a program with many and varied methods for extracting and filtering the information an ontology (.owl) file beholds, located in the filepath described by *ontdir* . Just a fragment of this program is cited below.

I have been studying the matter of using inference to create a richer model than the provided via inferring rules but, either I am still missing something basic or I need a veteran's assistance.

**Code:**

My up-to-now working code looks like this (it is C# obviously):

```
private Reasoner reasoner = null;
private OntModelSpec specs = null;
private OntModel m = null;
private string NS;
private string RDF;

public ontologyInfoRetriever (string ontdir)
    {
        try
        {
            this.m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
            this.m.read("file:///" + ontdir, "");
            //this.reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
            //this.reasoner = this.reasoner.bindSchema(m);
            //this.specs = OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM; //I tried diferent values here
            //this.specs.setReasoner(this.reasoner);
            //this.m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(this.specs, this.m);
            this.NS = this.m.getNsPrefixURI("doc");
            this.RDF = this.m.getNsPrefixURI("rdf");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log (e.ToString ());
        }
    }
```

And it works just as fine, only I am missing some information due to not using inference upon the model.

But when I uncomment the section, rebuild and import the .dll into a testing Unity program and play it... Unity freezes. 
I waited up to 5-10 minutes to see if it was just me being impatient but the memory usage just keeps stacking (I even reached ~1.8 GB when the owl file itself is no more than 90Kb) and does no good.

Please help me t_t

**Edit:** 
tried waiting even more. Memory usage reaged 5.4 Gb. Waiting aborted. What is taking so much time and memory? I suspect there's a loop entangling the reasoner but when I manage the ontology in Protege and use a reasoner there's no infernal loop of death :(

**Edit2:**
Real-life sources told me that jena only provides an interface for reasoners, and that you either configure a reasoner yourself or import a package with one (Hermit, Pellet, etc). Which lead me to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269896/how-to-compile-pellet-with-ikvmc)

Comment: How often do you call `ontologyInfoRetriever`? Every frame? Periodically? Once?

Comment: I instantiate it once using the ontology file provided via `ontdir` and then it is supposed to be used everytime you want to access to some information within the ontology, but such information is never manipulated, only extracted.
My testing program works like this:
`ontologyInfoRetriever r = new ontologyInfoRetriever (ontdir);`
`Dictionary<string,List<string>> dicc = r.getResourcesRelatedInformation("Document1");`

Comment: Are you using VS2015? Do you have any profiling tools?

Comment: Oh sry, I didn't really answer. The code above only runs once in `Start()`.
There is no `Update()` code nor any other method.

Comment: I am using mono-develop as the editor and I am anaware of profiling tools within it... yet. I think I can get to VS2015 if that helps in any way

Comment: Depending on the version, VS2015 has profiling tools built in that can tell you where your memory leaks are. There are also third party ones (that have demos) like JetBrains dotTrace. They can profile your application and tell you what is happening.

Comment: (cannot chat yet, too low a reputation) Currently downloading and installing VS2015 Comunity